# Jquery toggle incorrectly removing element from page

Tags: jquery, toggle

Can anyone tell why this works correctly to add and remove "hover" class to existing buttons on page:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
});
```

But when I try this instead, my buttons get an inline "display:none" tag  attached to them and disappear off the page?

```
$(".button").toggle(function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
},
function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

I'm on Win7 using Jquery 1.11.1 and was able to re-create issue in FF, Chrome an IE.

This is strictly a learning excercise, but any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: I can't find an overload of `toggle` which takes two functions, so it's not really clear what this is even *supposed* to do.  But given that the `toggle` function is used to hide or display elements, I would expect it to hide any matched elements which aren't already hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the .toggle method. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ According to the documentation, it's used to hide or display an element.

Comment: This is from an excerise book, is it just wrong? toggle()
This method attaches two event-handling functions to the selected element. syntax: .toggle(handler1, handler2)

Comment: tough luck, they need to add it to the errata

Comment: I'll check for it, thank you and thanks everybody for answering!

Answer (score 0):

The way it should be done is as following

```
$( ".button" ).hover(
function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
}, function() {
     $(this).removeClass("hover");
}
);
```